# After drag-and-drop operations, Selenium (Python) sometimes refuses to budge

Tags: python, selenium

After some dragging and dropping of elements into one another, the my program sometimes hangs. So I have a timeout set for it that runs the first block of code when the timer is reached. It does print the first line, but Selenium refuses to budge as `driver.close()` does not run after the `print` statement, and the rest of the code is rendered unreachable. The whole program hangs and cannot proceed. Is this a bug with Selenium or something I wrote?

```
print("This took too long. Will run a different function.")
driver.close()
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
sleep(2)
# REST OF CODE
```

Could it possibly be the drag-and-drop code?

```
if elementsToMove:
    a1 = random.choice(elementsToMove)
    a2 = random.choice(elementsToMove)
    while a1 == a2:
        a2 = random.choice(elementsToMove)
    actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)
    actions.drag_and_drop(a1, a2)
    actions.perform()
```

Comment: Can you sum up your Manual Steps you are trying to Automate?

Comment: what if `a1 == a2` forever? it will be spinning in that loop, and it may look like complete hanging since CPU will e at 100% and busy. You could check that you have something to choose form first, or limit total number of iterations.

Comment: @DebanjanB I'm trying to drag one element into another. The elements cannot be the same.

Comment: @KirilS. You raise a good pint there. I rewrote this to make two lists, one full and one with `a1` one missing. The same issue occurs.

Comment: could be a real chrome driver issue then. I'd get verbose chrome log (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging) and submit issue to chrome developers (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/list). They may guide you on what to check/look for

Comment: @KirilS. Actually was using geckodriver. Could be an undocumented old version issue (the version I'm using is one of the only I know works on the Raspberry Pi). Thanks for confirming it may not be my code, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later, I will answer my own question.

1. I cringe reading my old code. I should have used `sample`, not `choice` twice.
2. I'm pretty sure it was a geckodriver issue. I don't know what fixed it, but it did get fixed.